# Understanding Google Maps overlay type from object (polygon or polyLine)?

Tags: google-maps-api

```
var Line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path:predectionArray,
    editable: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });


var Rect=new google.maps.Polygon({
    path:predectionArray2,
    editable: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

the object Line is poly Line and Rect is Polygon .The question is how can i retrive it's type from Object name ,Like Rect.type or Line.type ?

Comment: object=newobject.type

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to your drawing manager and check using `obj.type` to check for the type of shape drawn.
Eg:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 39.810866, lng: -104.990347}
}
var circleOptions = {
    fillColor: '#ffff00',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: '#ffff00',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 0.3,
    clickable: false,
    editable: true,
    zIndex: 1
}'

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                      drawingMode: null,
                      drawingControl: true,
                      drawingControlOptions: {
                          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                          drawingModes: ['circle', 'polygon', 'rectangle']
                      },
                      markerOptions: {icon: 'markerImage.png'},
                      circleOptions: circleOptions
                 });
drawingManager.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', 
onOverlayComplete);`
```

> function onOverlayComplete(shape) {
>
> > ```
> > if(shape == null || (shape.type.length == 0 || shape.type == null)) { return;  }
> > ```
>
> ```
>  if (shape.type == 'polygon') {
>      alert("Polygon");
>  }
>
>  if (shape.type == 'circle') {
>     alert("Circle");
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Use your own image for the marker icon or search for one online.